# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'bytes' and 'int'

Tags: python

i need to subtract 481310 from the variable data but i get this error.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'bytes' and 'int'
It's in python.
I want to subtract 481310 from the variable because it should be 0 but for some reason it's 481310 if someone know other way to fix it let me know!

```
   import serial
    import serial.tools.list_ports
    import sys

    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
            ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
    result = []
    for port in ports:
           try:
               s = serial.Serial(port)
               s.close()
               result.append(port)
           except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
               pass
    #print result[1]
    #ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    #print ports[1]
    arduino = serial.Serial(result[1], 9600)

    try:
        while True:
            data = arduino.readline()
            data -= 481310
            if data:
                #print data
                datalist = list(data)
                #print len(datalist)
                #print datalist
                str1 = ''.join([str(i) for i in datalist])
                #print str1
                f = open('data.txt', 'a')
                f.write(str1+ '\n')
                f.close()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            arduino.close()
            quit
```